# Notepad++ regex Replace, using match variables

Tags: notepad++, regex

In Notepad++, I want to perform a find-and-replace, providing a variable in the 'Replace with' field, which references a match from the 'Find what' field. Any ideas?

I tried supplying (find) `foo (\w) bar` (replace) `foo baz ($1) bar qux`. That didn't work.

Comment: Try \1 instead.

Comment: Easy rep there if someone wants to write up a nice answer. I don't use Notepad++ so I didn't make it an answer. I do however use google and figured the OP would appreciate something that would solve the issue even if it wasn't a proper answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notepad++ [uses standard POSIX](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/searching/normal-search) regular expressions. As such, [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) should use the slash instead of the dollar-sign:

```
Find    : foo (\w) bar
Replace : foo baz (\1) bar qux
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a token identifier. So if I modified Synetech's answer, I would change "Find" part to "foo (?'one'\w+) bar"

Comment: It would help if you can test the solution and provide an answer, Starting an answer as "i think" doesn't show confidence, and you might get down votes

Comment: Fair enough. I was trying to add to the existing answer.